# How do I Login inside app to use GPPNativeShareBuilder of Google API in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, google-plus, share, google-signin

I am using `Google Plus API` for login purpose.

My app rejects once due to `GPPSignIn (Not Google login within app)`, then I used `GTMOAuth2Authentication` for login with Google. This allow me to login inside my app. 
This goes well.

I am worrying about share on Google, for same issue (rejection), I implemented `GPPNativeShareBuilder`, which allows me to share within app, but this goes out of app for login, when tried with same `GTMOAuth2Authentication` this gives me error message:-

```
[GPPNativeShareBuilderImpl open] User must be signed in to use the native share box.
```

I used this also

> GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init];
>   [plusService setAuthorizer:self.auth];  // authentication object!!!

This produces same warning error, not presents share dialog.

Help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Could not able to set the authorization for native share disalog